# Excel VBA: Isolate script to one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is intended to convert strings of text into a concise array in one sheet, but it keeps changing text in other sheets within the workbook.

I've highlighted the block where I think the problem is arising by surrounding it with the comments `#below` and `#above`.

How can I make this run on a specified sheet only?

```
Sub Convert()

    Rows(2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows(3).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows(4).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    '##Below

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fndList As Variant
    Dim rplcList As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    fndList = Array(" CR 0.00 0.00 ", " DR 0.00 0.00 ", " 0.00 ", " Cr", " Dr", "0.00", "0.00 ")
    rplcList = Array(";-", ";", ";", "", "", "", "")
    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next sht

        '##Above    
    Next x

    Range("A1") = "Account"
    Range("C1") = "Balance"
    Range("D1") = "KP"
    Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns _
    Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True
    Columns("B:C").AutoFit
    Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Columns(2).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Range("C:C").AutoFilter 1, "<>", , , False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Below** section you have this loop:

```
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next sht
```

Which means you are doing the `Replace` for all sheets.

Change it to:

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName") '<-- modify to your sheet's name

sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Also, to be on the safe side, for the **Above** section, fully qualify your `Range` objects with the `sht`. see example below:

```
With sht
    .Range("A1") = "Account"
    .Range("C1") = "Balance"
    .Range("D1") = "KP"

    ' rest of your code

End With
```

Comment: @YowE3K it's almost 8:00 AM

Comment: @YowE3K I have little kids, and I run in the mornings, I wake up at 04:30 every day :(

Comment: Thanks so much Shai! I can't wait to try this out - I'll let you know how it goes tomorrow!

Comment: Working beautifully thank you Shai! What a hoot! Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @ChrisJenks you're welcome, now comes you part where you mark this as "ANSWER", by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer (it will turn green)

Comment: Haha, oh yup newbie mistake! Done

Comment: @ChrisJenks  it's ok, we are here to help :)